# Invalid column executing a linq with entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4.1

I created this class

```
public class Usuario
{
    #region Atributos
    private int _intID = 0;
    private Perfil _Perfil_FK = null;
    private String _strNombre = "";
    private String _strPassword = "";
    #endregion

    #region Propiedades
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _intID; }
        set { _intID = value; }
    }
    public virtual Perfil Perfil_FK
    {
        get { return _Perfil_FK; }
        set { _Perfil_FK = value; }
    }
    public String Nombre
    {
        get { return _strNombre; }
        set { _strNombre = value; }
    }
    public String Password
    {
        get { return _strPassword; }
        set { _strPassword = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In my context I defined this properties

```
protected override void    OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

and in some part of my code i do this linq

`Usuario user = (from U in _db.Usuario where ((U.Nombre == model.UserName) && (U.Password == encripPassword)) select U).First();`

Resulting in this exepcion `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Perfil_FK_ID'.` What Could be the problem?, for me the code it's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a navigational property `Perfil_FK` of type `Perfil`. But you haven't specified the foreign key column to be used with that relationship. So EF by conventions assumes the foreign key column name is `Perfil_FK_ID`.

You haven't given any information about the relationship between `Usuario` and `Perfil`. There are few different ways to configure the relationship depending on your model.